# YouTube isn't receiving any data from my FFmpeg stream to the RTMP server

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

So I have a Python program running on my computer that is sending the same image to an RTMP server every second: it is reading the image and then sending the data. From the console everything seems OK, but YouTube says that its not receiving any data.

Here is my code:

```py
import subprocess
import cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<valid-rtmp-id>"

fps = 1.5

width = 600
height = 600

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
  f = cv2.imread('assets/temporary.png')

  p.stdin.write(f.tobytes())
```

My console's output is:

```sh
[rtmp @ 0x28d9940] Server response validating failed
<VideoCapture 0x7f60895dafb0>
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12960 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 600x600, 12960 kb/s, 1.50 fps, 1.50 tbr, 1.50 tbn, 1.50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[libx264 @ 0x5613ba2e3d40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5613ba2e3d40] profile High, level 2.2
[libx264 @ 0x5613ba2e3d40] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key>':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 600x600, q=-1--1, 1.50 fps, 1k tbn, 1.50 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   55 fps=0.0 q=19.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:01.33 bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube needs audio. Use the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) to generate silent audio.

```
import subprocess
import cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<valid-rtmp-id>"

fps = 1.5

width = 600
height = 600

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
           '-video_size', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-framerate', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-re',
           '-f', 'lavfi',
           '-i', 'anullsrc',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-c:a', 'aac',
           '-vf', 'format=yuv420p',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
  f = cv2.imread('assets/temporary.png')

  p.stdin.write(f.tobytes())
```

- I'm doubtful YouTube likes 1.5 fps, buut I did not test. If that is the case add `-r 10` output option.
- It's best to also add the `-g`, `-b:v`, `-maxrate`, and `-bufsize` options when [streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

Comment: So it worked but the image is trash. i'm sending this (https://ibb.co/3dnq5Mw) image to youtube and this is what i'm receiving from youtube (https://ibb.co/bRzcBD3). How would I make it be better?

Comment: @EniolaOyewole Possibly incorrect `-pixel_format` value. Not a solution, but remove `-r 10`: your `-framerate` is now 30 which is normal so no need for `-r` (which you placed in wrong location anyway).

Comment: do you think you can help me fix pixel_format? i want to get this to display the image 100% correctly to the youtube live stream @llogan

Comment: @EniolaOyewole Actually I think it is incorrect `-video_size`. The example image is 225x225, but you are telling ffmpeg the input is 600x600. Change it to 225x225 and then add [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to `-vf` if you want it to be 600x600, as in `-vf scale=600:600,format=yuv420p`.